# Javafx how to trigger a stage layout update

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a very simple Javafx application, that displays a form backed by a grid. On this form I have a checkbox. When the user checks this checkbox, I want to dynamically add another row to the grid.

From my controller:

```java
checkbox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) - > {
    if (!newVal) {
        // Add Username Label
        gridPane.add(new Label("Username : "), 0, 5);

        // Add Username Text Field
        gridPane.add(new TextField(), 1, 5);
    }
});
```

The above code works just fine, the only problem is the window layout is not updated to show the new row (I mean the height is not automatically increased), unless I manually resize the window.

**Question** How to trigger a layout update? (I tried `gridPane.requestLayout()` but it has no effect)

**UPDATE**

An ugly workaround would be to hide then show the stage again.

Comment: Are you wanting to *resize* the stage to accommodate the new row? `stage.sizeToScene()` should do that (call it after you add the row)

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resize a stage to the size of its content, you can use the inherited [`sizeToScene()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#sizeToScene()) method. The following will resize the stage to respond to your new row:

```java
checkbox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) - > {

    if (!newVal) {
        // Add Username Label
        gridPane.add(new Label("Username : "), 0, 5);

        // Add Username Text Field
        gridPane.add(new TextField(), 1, 5);
        gridPane.getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
    }
});
```